# How do I style the body image of the home page differently than other pages in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, background, components, styling

I tried using useEffect and it worked for background color!  But when I tried to make it work with background image it won't work:

```
useEffect(() => {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/5566.jpg')";
    }, []);
```

What could I be doing wrong if it's working with background color but not image?

Is there another approach I can use to style the home page body differently than the rest of the pages?  Class on a div won't work because I'm trying to style the whole body so I get the white space behind the nav as well.  Any thoughts much appreciated and welcomed!

Comment: it's not recognizing the path because when I use a web image URL it works...

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the component for the home page in a component that has the background image set normally.